# Is there a way to upgrade from a Heroku shared database to a production grade database like Basic or Crane?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, migration

I have been using the Heroku shared database for a while now in an app and I would like to upgrade to their new Basic/Crane/etc. production grade databases. I don't however see a clear path to do that.

The options as I see them are:

1. I could use db:pull/db:push to migrate data/schema from the current production database to the new database. I could go into maintenance mode, move the data, then update the config to point to the new database. Not terrible, but I fear that the old schema from the shared database is not v9 compatible? Maybe I'm wrong. This could also take a long time resulting in some major downtime. Not cool.
2. Use pg:backups to create a backup, and use the heroku pg:restore to move the data over. Again I fear the same schema issues but this would be much faster.
3. Start with a Basic/Crane database and use their Followers concept. This feels like the right way to do it, but I don't know if this works with the shared databases. If it does I do not understand how.

All of these options I feel require me to upgrade to postgres v9 at some point since all the new databases are v9. Is there a way to do this in the shared environment, and then maybe migrating will be less painful... maybe.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Their [Migrating Between Databases](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/migrating-data-between-plans/) document points out that your option (3) using Followers for a fast changeover doesn't work when you're starting with a shared instance.  What you should do here is use pg:backups to make a second database to test your application against and confirm the new database acts correctly there.  If that works, turn on maintenance mode and do it again for the real migration.

There's very few schema level incompatibility issues going between PostgreSQL 8.4 and 9.1.  That migration doc warns about one of them, the Bytea changes.  If you're using Bytea, you probably know it; it's not that common.  Most of the other things changed between those versions are also features you're unlikely to use, such as the [PL/pgSQL modifications](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.0#PL.2FpgSQL_changes_which_may_cause_regressions) made in PostgreSQL 9.0.  Again, if you're using PL/pgSQL server-side functions, you'll probably know that too, and most people on Heroku don't.

Answer (score 1):

Don't guess if your database is compatible, test. You can run multiple copies of PostgreSQL locally, they just need different data directories and ports configured. That way you can test against 9.1 and 8.4 at will.

You usually use the pg_dump from 9.1 to dump the 8.4 database - pg_dump knows about older versions, but not newer (obviously).

Unless you're doing something unusual with the database (presumably not, since you're on Heroku) then there's unlikely to be any problems just dumping + restoring between versions.